# Custom format ID mapping

Tags: python, r, bash

I have two databases (txt files). One is a two-column, tab-delimited one, that holds names and IDs.

```
name1 \t ID1
name1 \t ID2
name2 \t ID9
name2 \t ID40
name3 \t ID3
```

The other database has the same IDs as the first one in the first column, while the second column lists IDs of the same kind delimited by commas (these are the children of the ones in the first one, as the second database is hierarchical).

```
ID1 \t ID1,ID2,ID3
ID2 \t ID2, ID9
```

What I would like to do is get a third database with the same format as the second, but in the second column I'd like to swap out the children IDs to the names of the first database. For example:

```
ID1 \t name1,name2,name3
ID2 \t name1,name2
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm quite the beginner, when I had to map IDs before I used web services, but this is a custom format needed for further analysis and I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Databases = tables ? Are the table flat files ?

Comment: Yes, they are simple txt files, sorry if I wasn't being clear.

Comment: This may be too general of a question, especially with tagging the question in python, r, and bash.

Comment: Can you write code to read the files, and separate the parts?  If so, do that, post it and show what isn't working

Comment: @dayne Sorry if I was being vague, I tagged those things because those are the ones I understand on some level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

# Reading the first db is simple since there's only a fixed delimiter
# Use csv module to split the lines and create a dictionary that maps id to name

id_dictionary = {}
with open('db_1.txt', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        id_dictionary[line[1]] = line[0]

# We can again split on tab but that will return 'name1,name2' etc as a single 
# string that we call split() on later.

row_data = []
with open('db_2.txt', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        # ID remains unchanged, so keep the first value
        row = [line[0]]

        # Split the string into individual elements in a list
        id_codes = line[1].split(',')

        # List comprehension to look for ID in the dictionary and return the
        # name stored against it
        translated = [id_dictionary.get(item) for item in id_codes]

        # Add translated to the list that we are using to represent a row
        row.extend(translated)

        # Append the row to our collection of rows
        row_data.append(row)

with open('db_3.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in row_data:
        outfile.write(row[0])
        outfile.write('\t')
        outfile.write(','.join(map(str,row[1:]))) # Join values by a comma
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly and I was able to comprehend it :). I added `import.sys` and `csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)` for it to work, since the text files had some pretty huge fields.

Comment: @MártonOelbei I didn't realise the files were that big. Surely it would be worth looking at a different storage system, either a database or something like a cpickle file as the output, not another text file? Otherwise you're relegated to scanning everything line by line every time you want to find something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one line awk script:

```
awk -v FS="\t|," -v OFS="," 'FILENAME=="file_name.txt" {str[$2]=$1;next;} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {sub($i,str[$i],$i)};a=$1;$1="";print a"\t"$0}' file_name.txt fileID.txt|sed -e 's/,//' -e 's/,$//'
```

The "file_name.txt" for the awk is the txt file whose first columns have the "name1,name2..." while the "fileID.txt"  has in the first column the "ID1,ID2,..."

The sed is to trim the commas at the beginning and at the end of the list that are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
#suppose database files are f1.txt,f2.txt,f3.txt
#use set to get key-value format datas
def getArr(f):
    i=f.readline()
    arr=[]
    while i:
        i=i.replace('\n','')
        arr.append(i.split('\t'))
        i=f.readline()
    return arr
if __name__=="__main__":
    f1=file("f1.txt")
    f2=file("f2.txt")
    f3=open('f3.txt','w')
    arr1=getArr(f1)
    arr2=getArr(f2)
    dic={}
    for array in arr1:
        dic[array[1]]=array[0]
    for i in arr2:
        keys=i[1].split(',')
        print keys
        line=i[0]+'\t'
        for key in keys:
            line+=dic.get(key)+','
        line=line[:-1]+'\n'
        f3.write(line)
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    f3.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds compared to my answer submitted some time before this. It provides no explanation, does not use a context manager to handle the files and is really confusing to read. `line+=dic.get(key)+','` is not good practice at all.